# Why java queue fail to poll data in some case?

Tags: java, queue, sleep

Below code can show 0~9 in console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("start");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            queue.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }).start();

    while (true) {
        String data = queue.poll();
        if (data != null) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
```

---

But why below code cannot? 
The only difference is the adding thread sleep for one second before adding each data into the queue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("start");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            queue.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }).start();

    while (true) {
        String data = queue.poll();
        if (data != null) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any response!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does the trick:

```
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.Queue; 
  public class HelloWorld{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("start");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                 queue.add(String.valueOf(i));
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {//InterruptedException
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println("end");
    }).start();

    while (true) {
        String data = queue.poll();
        if (data != null) {
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation, i'm trying to solve some more complicated problem, just reproduce it using this simple example, thanks!